# Add '+' sign using Flex NumberFormatter

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I want to format a number with the '+' or '-' sign attached to it. When i tried with the useNegativeSign=true, it gave only '-' sign. 
I want like this : +13%, -12%, ...

Thanks in Advance,
Cheers,PK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to write your own Formatter for this, to prepend the symbol and append the percent sign.

[Creating a formatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf68b24-7ff9.html)

Comment: thanx Gregor, I think thats the perfect solution for my query... :)